# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, when router hits for the second time

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Getting below exception for the router navigation when click for the second time, however there is no error for the first time click to same routerlink.

Also, when I enter url directly in the browser and press enter button it is working fine.
I checked all the modules and there is no cyclic dependency (otherwise it should have give me error for the first time).
Please help me here.

ERROR -

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at router.mjs:2188:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at setRouterState (router.mjs:2188:19)
    at router.mjs:2188:32
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at setRouterState (router.mjs:2188:19)
    at router.mjs:2188:32
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at setRouterState (router.mjs:2188:19)
    at router.mjs:2188:32
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:17)
    at zone.js:1278:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26194:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:585:35)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:491:21)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1661:18)
handleError @ core.mjs:7621
next @ core.mjs:26900
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.mjs:22729
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:26233
invoke @ zone.js:372
run @ zone.js:134
runOutsideAngular @ core.mjs:26106
onHandleError @ core.mjs:26233
handleError @ zone.js:376
runGuarded @ zone.js:147
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:1072
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:592
invokeTask @ zone.js:491
invokeTask @ zone.js:1661
globalCallback @ zone.js:1692
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1725
Show 21 more frames
```

I am using angular 14.2.9 version and below is the router constant using for main module

```
export const mainRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('../home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'viewers',
        loadChildren: () => import('../viewers/viewers.module').then(m => m.ViewersModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'viewers/:name',
        loadChildren: () => import('../viewers/viewers.module').then(m => m.ViewersModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboards',
        loadChildren: () => import('../dashboards/dashboards.module').then(m => m.DashboardsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'ccs-emulators',
        loadChildren: () => import('../ccs-emulator-container/ccs-emulator-container.module').then(m => m.CcsEmulatorContainerModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'ccs-emulators/:name',
        loadChildren: () => import('../ccs-emulator-container/ccs-emulator-container.module').then(m => m.CcsEmulatorContainerModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'configurations',
        loadChildren: () => import('../configurations/configurations.module').then(m => m.ConfigurationsModule)
      }
    ]
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(mainRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutingModule { }
```

Dashboard Routes -

```
export const dashboardsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'sessions',
        loadChildren: () => import('../sessions-dashboard/sessions-dashboard.module').then(m => m.SessionsDashboardModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(dashboardsRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardsRoutingModule { }
```

AuthGaurd -

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  private isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return this.authService.isLoginRequired()
      ? this.authService.isLoggedIn()
      : true;
  }
}
```

Console Error -
[image]

Comment: Can you include any guards and interceptors that your application registers? For example auth guard. You might have some that perform redirection to the same route and get into this infinite redirect

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu, added authgaurd code, please take a look

Comment: I don't see anything relevant in the code you included. I recommend you to inject the `Router` in the app component and subscribe to the router events. See if you can make any sense from what you see in the console. `router.events.subscribe(e => console.log(e));`

Comment: I tried capture logs as you have suggested but not getting what is the exact error, added the screen shot in post, please take a look

Comment: Im not sure at all, but, can the problem be around the path with `viewers` and `viewers/:name` and the same with ccs-emulators? Both path points to the same module but with different route. Try agrouping both in just one module and create a ChildRoute for that, with the home child path is '' and the other is ':/name'

Comment: Can you also include the `DashboardsRoutingModule`? See if that one has any guards that could trigger the infinite loop.

Comment: Dashboard module is having moduleroutes inside moduleroutes, the way you suggested above but that too have same issue. Added Dashboard module routes in post